# how to remove or delete selected file from React-Dropzone

Tags: reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I have the following code and I am trying to remove or delete a selected file when the x button is press. Currently I am able to upload a image by drag and drop. I can see a preview of the image. I have added a button at the top left of the preview. When click it should be remove. I am not sure how to do this.

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import ToggleButton from "@mui/material/ToggleButton";
import ClearIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Clear";

const thumbsContainer = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  marginTop: 16,
};

const thumb = {
  display: "inline-flex",
  borderRadius: 2,
  border: "1px solid #eaeaea",
  marginBottom: 8,
  marginRight: 8,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  padding: 4,
  boxSizing: "border-box",
};

const thumbInner = {
  display: "flex",
  minWidth: 0,
  overflow: "hidden",
};

const img = {
  display: "block",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
};

const clearBtn = {
  position: "absolute",
  width: 5,
  height: 5,
};

export const Uploader = (props) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      "image/*": [],
    },
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setFiles(
        acceptedFiles.map((file, index) =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
            id: index,
          })
        )
      );
    },
  });

  const thumbs = files.map((file) => (
    <div style={thumb} key={file.name}>
      <div style={thumbInner}>
        <ToggleButton
          value="left"
          key="left"
          sx={clearBtn}
          onClick={() => removeFile}
        >
          <ClearIcon />
        </ToggleButton>
        <img
          src={file.preview}
          style={img}
          // Revoke data uri after image is loaded
          onLoad={() => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks, will run on unmount
    return () => files.forEach((file) => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
      <aside style={thumbsContainer}>{thumbs}</aside>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Uploader;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove file from react-dropzone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025690/how-to-remove-file-from-react-dropzone)